# How to set a variable as a an address from the .find function in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Here is a snippet of what I have right now. The ListBoxAsset is a selection from a listbox. Right now it throws an error 91 on the first offset/delete row. Any help or feedback is much appreciated!!!

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim assetName As Long
assetName = ListBoxAsset.Value

Dim rgFound As Range
Set rgFound = Range("B4:B18").Find(assetName)


Dim assetLoc  As Range
If Not rgFound Is Nothing Then assetLoc = rgFound.Address

assetLoc.Offset(0, 0).Delete (xlShiftUp)
assetLoc.Offset(0, 1).Delete (xlShiftUp)
assetLoc.Offset(0, 2).Delete (xlShiftUp)



Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? You don't want to use the `Address` here at all - that's a `String`.

Comment: `rgFound.Resize(,3).Delete xlShiftUp`